# Reference for Cardinality of Parabolic Subgroup of Symplectic Group over Finite Fields

Tags: finite-fields, symplectic-linear-algebra, maximal-subgroup

I am looking for a source to reference that gives the cardinality of parabolic subgroups of the Symplectic group $Sp$ over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$. What I want is essentially exactly what is in [these lecture notes](https://math.mit.edu/%7Edav/symplectic_parabolic.pdf), but I need a proper citable source for it. Particularly, something which proves the cardinalities of the Levi and unipotent radical subgroups and concludes with (for some isotropic subspace of $\mathbb F_q^n$)
$$|P(S)| = |N|\cdot |GL(k,\mathbb F_q)|\cdot |Sp(n-k, \mathbb F_q)|$$
and thus get
$$|P(S)| = q^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+2k(n-k)} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (q^k-q^i) q^{(n-k)^2} \prod_{j=1}^{n-k}(q^{2j}-1)$$
Where $n$ is the dimension of the space initially and $k$ is the dimension of the isotropic subspace that is being stabalized.

Comment: It might be that this is too elementary to have a biggish citeable source...

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes I agree... unfortunately the proofs are a bit too long to add to an appendix of my submission.

Comment: Possibly a "slick", terse indication of proofs would fit in (and be actually useful to readers). Might be an interesting exercise to explain things... approximately ... in relatively few words. :)